# Как в C# asp.net MVC Resource файлы(localization) перевести в бд(mssql)?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

У меня есть ресурс файлы для перевода языка на сайте но я хочу чтобы они хранились также и в дб(mssql), для того чтобы через админ панель можно было делать изменения. Как мне это реализовать? Я создал модель ResourceData с Name, Value как мне сделать чтобы name value из ресурс файлов попадал в в эту модель. Проект написан на C#, .Net7, Asp.Net core(MVC)

Comment: Ваша БД не должна ничего знать про язык, она должна оперировать данными, а не тем, как эти данные показать клиенту. Перевод - это UI, вот там это и применяйте.

Comment: Удобство Resource-файлов в том, что данные берутся из них автоматически. Работу с БД придётся делать ручками. Читать данные из БД, подставляете в модель.